# firebase login isn't working when I tried running it on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase

"firebase : The term 'firebase' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again."

[here is error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO6Z3.png)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [firebase login using power shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369778/firebase-login-using-power-shell)

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed firebase-tools globally using npm or yarn?
You can see your globally installed npm packages with:

```
npm list -g --depth 0
```

And globally installed yarn packages with:

```
yarn global list
```

So see if you have installed firebase-tools globally and install or reinstall them and try to see again i "firebase login" command works then.

Comment: I 've almost done everything from uninstalling-reinstalling to changing paths but firebase has never worked for me.

Comment: @Digambernegi I would then look at the link that ADyson commented to your original question. I think that will help you, but tell if the problem still persist.

Comment: probably no. Now it shows `firebase.ps1` could not be loaded due to running scripts is disabled. Should I go for **Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope CurrentUser** !!

Comment: I don't have more information about that error you are now encountering. I hope you find answer to that in some posts